# Whole company / group calendar invites in O365

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

What is the best way in Office 365/Exchange Online to create a recurring calendar invite for an entire company, or a particular group, that automatically appears in the calendars of everyone as they are added to the group.

For example, a whole company monthly or weekly meeting. With regular calendar entries any new employees would have to be manually invited, as well as any departing employees manually removed.

Comment: There a lots of problems with recurring meeting invites in Outlook. Best practice is that you don’t even allow meetings to recur more than for 6 months. The other best practice is that you don’t send meeting invites to distribution groups. You do not want to be making lots of changes to a recurring meeting. In any case you will have problems.  There are several other technologies available to you to do this. But you should simply ask your users to subscribe to a company calendar feed. Web feeds can be enabled in OWA if the option isn’t available in Outlook.

Comment: @Appleoddity If they subscribe to a calendar will it insert entries into their own?

Comment: I’m pretty sure it acts just like another calendar. What it looks like in Outlook is dependent on your view settings.